# why does division of NSNumber by float gives result rounded to 1 decimal place?

Tags: objective-c, ios, floating-point, decimal-point

See the following code:

```
NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemFreeSize];
float totalSpaceInMB = (([fileSystemSizeInBytes longLongValue] /1024.0)/1024.0);
```

Here `totalSpaceInMB` is always rounded off to 1 decimal place.

For example, if `fileSystemSizeInBytes = 13261987840`, then `totalSpaceInMB = 12647.6`

I want 4 decimal places, `totalSpaceInMB = 12647.6172`. Why is this happening?

Comment: How are you displaying the number??

Comment: (And keep in mind that a float only has about 6 significant digits. Use double if you want more.)

Comment: (Not that it makes much sense to display total MB to that level of precision.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemFreeSize];

double totalSpaceInMB = (([fileSystemSizeInBytes longLongValue] /1024.0)/1024.0);

NSLog(@"%.4f",totalSpaceInMB);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This NSLog do gives output to 4 decimal. But I have to further calculation based on space in MB (totalSpaceInMB / x). While doing this, totalSpaceInMB is taken as 1 decimal point & not 4 decimal point. So I am not getting precise value.

Comment: double totalSpaceInMB = fabs((([fileSystemSizeInBytes longLongValue] /1024.0)/1024.0));

NSLog(@"%.4f",totalSpaceInMB);

Answer (score 0):

Better Try out :

```
NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemFreeSize];
double totalSpaceInMB = (([fileSystemSizeInBytes longLongValue] /1024.0)/1024.0);
NSLog(@"%.4lf",totalSpaceInMB);
```

Comment: This NSLog do gives output to 4 decimal. But I have to further calculation based on space in MB (totalSpaceInMB / x). While doing this, totalSpaceInMB is taken as 1 decimal point & not 4 decimal point. So I am not getting precise value.